# Emit mapper. Convert object to int

Tags: c#, .net, emitmapper

I have some trouble when I try to map `object` to `int`.
My classes and method where convert:

```
[Serializable]
public class ProfileProperty
{
    public object PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public ProfileProperty(object value, bool isVisible = true)
    {
        this.PropertyValue = value;
        this.IsVisible = isVisible;
    }

    public ProfileProperty()
    {
        this.IsVisible = true;
    }

    public T GetValue<T>()
    {
        return (T)this.PropertyValue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this.PropertyValue != null)
        {
            return this.PropertyValue.ToString();
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ProfileProperty
{
    public object PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public ProfileProperty(object value, bool isVisible = true)
    {
        this.PropertyValue = value;
        this.IsVisible = isVisible;
    }

    public ProfileProperty()
    {
        this.IsVisible = true;
    }

    public T GetValue<T>()
    {
        return (T)this.PropertyValue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this.PropertyValue != null)
        {
            return this.PropertyValue.ToString();
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public static class Helper
{
    public static ProfileModel PopulProfMod(Profile profile)
    {
        var mapper = ObjectMapperManager.DefaultInstance.GetMapper<Profile, ProfileModel>(new DefaultMapConfig()
                    .IgnoreMembers<Profile, ProfileModel>(new string[] { "GetValue", "ToString" }));
        ProfileModel prof = new ProfileModel();
        if (profile != null)
        {
            prof = mapper.Map(profile);
            //prof.Age = (int)profile.Age.PropertyValue;
            prof.Visibility = new List<string>();
        }

        //Some code

        return prof;
    }
}
```

When mapped property `Age` is 0 but `profile`:

```
Profile profile = new Profile()
            {
                Age = new ProfileProperty() { IsVisible = true, PropertyValue = 17 },
                Comments = 2,
                UserName = "Luck",
                FirstName = new ProfileProperty() { IsVisible = false, PropertyValue = "Alex" }
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a converter:

```
  new DefaultMapConfig()
       .IgnoreMembers<Profile, ProfileModel>(new string[] { "GetValue", "ToString" }))
       .ConvertUsing<ProfileProperty, int>(s => (int)s.PropertyValue)
```